# Microsoft Graph Excel get chart not implemented

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am using MS Graph to [load a chart](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/chart_get) from an Excel file.

It works for many chart types but if I try to retrieve a **Histogram chart** Graph returns the following error:

```json
{  
   "code":"UnsupportedOperation",
   "message":"This operation is not implemented.",
   "innerError":{  
      "request-id":"3085f0fc-c785-45bf-ab65-1833e9fed648",
      "date":"2018-03-25T06:47:28"
   }
}
```

Which chart types are supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it supports the same set as the Excel Web Add-in's [`ChartCollection.Add()` method](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/chartcollection#addtype-string-sourcedata-object-seriesby-string):

> `ColumnClustered`, `ColumnStacked`, `ColumnStacked100`, `_3DColumnClustered`, `_3DColumnStacked`, `_3DColumnStacked100`, `BarClustered`, `BarStacked`, `BarStacked100`, `_3DBarClustered`, `_3DBarStacked`, `_3DBarStacked100`, `LineStacked`, `LineStacked100`, `LineMarkers`, `LineMarkersStacked`, `LineMarkersStacked100`, `PieOfPie`, `PieExploded`, `_3DPieExploded`, `BarOfPie`, `XYScatterSmooth`, `XYScatterSmoothNoMarkers`, `XYScatterLines`, `XYScatterLinesNoMarkers`, `AreaStacked`, `AreaStacked100`, `_3DAreaStacked`, `_3DAreaStacked100`, `DoughnutExploded`, `RadarMarkers`, `RadarFilled`, `Surface`, `SurfaceWireframe`, `SurfaceTopView`, `SurfaceTopViewWireframe`, `Bubble`, `Bubble3DEffect`, `StockHLC`, `StockOHLC`, `StockVHLC`, `StockVOHLC`, `CylinderColClustered`, `CylinderColStacked`, `CylinderColStacked100`, `CylinderBarClustered`, `CylinderBarStacked`, `CylinderBarStacked100`, `CylinderCol`, `ConeColClustered`, `ConeColStacked`, `ConeColStacked100`, `ConeBarClustered`, `ConeBarStacked`, `ConeBarStacked100`, `ConeCol`, `PyramidColClustered`, `PyramidColStacked`, `PyramidColStacked100`, `PyramidBarClustered`, `PyramidBarStacked`, `PyramidBarStacked100`, `PyramidCol`, `_3DColumn`, `Line`,  `_3DLine`, `_3DPie`, `Pie`, `XYScatter`, `_3DArea`, `Area`, `Doughnut`, `Radar`

That said, it sure seems like this should be supported (in both Microsoft Graph and Office.js). I'd suggest opening a [UserVoice for Histogram Chart support](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).